# Creating an app, but I wanna make it so that the user selects their profile picture from preset pictures

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8

So I'm making an app and I wanna make it so that when the user selects their profile picture they select it out of images that I have already put into the app, not their own camera roll or photo album.

I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3, and Firebase to make this.

Comment: Good for you man! I also want to build an app that helps old people in my country be less brain-washed (wait, do they know what an app is?). Maybe we'll both get what we want, but for starters please click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44749488/edit)** 
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the photos in the app's in the bundle and display them in a collection or table view for selection.

If you do not know how to do any or some of those things, the the program you are writing is too advanced for you. First do a couple of tutorials to familiarize yourself with the basics.